# How to import GitHub source code to jupyter Note Book

Tags: python, github, jupyter

I'm facing a problem to import github source code into my jupyter notebook.I want to download a source code from github and want to import it into my jupyter editor.Please help that how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GitHub Version Control for Jupyter Notebooks

For more info you can refer the [link](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/jupyter-notebooks/managing-jupy-notebook-versions/link-jupy-notebook-github.html)